# Regex - Ignore commented xml line with multiple captures

Tags: javascript, regex

So I've got some xml I'm trying to reformat, and I'm trying to find all the key/value pairs. Everything works except when I've got a commented line that contains the keys. Here are the lines in question:

```
<!-- <add key="FTPRoot" value="\\productionshare\FTP" /> -->
<add key="FTPRoot" value="C:\FTP" />
```

The first line should be ignored, and the second line should end up with four captures (two matches, two captures each). The regex below allows for multiple captures, and behaves correctly for the second line, but also incorrectly (I don't account for it, the regex is not to blame) picks up the first line:

`/(\S*)=(["].*?["])/g`

This will ignore the first line, but fails to match twice on the second line, thereby granting me by four captures.

`/<[^!].*?(\S*?)=(["]\S*["])/g`

So, what am I missing to get the captures I need. I can make a whole line match even if needed, it's just that second capture I'm missing.

Comment: If this in in javascript, as opposed to using a regex I recommend an xml to json converter. https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js

Comment: It might be simpler to parse the whole XML then re-generate it.

Comment: What if the comment is multi line?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use regex, the following should work:

```
/<!--(?:.|\n)*?-->|(\S*)="(.*?)"/g
```

This matches the commented line but doesn't create captures. This means you can ignore the full matches and the captures have what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the `#comment` node from possibility of being matched by not passing the entire `XML` document as string to `RegExp`. Iterate the `XML` `documentElememt` `.childNodes` and perform task only at nodes that are not `#comment` nodes.

```html
<script>
let str = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><!-- <add key="FTPRoot" value="\\productionshare\FTP" /> -->
<add key="FTPRoot" value="C:\FTP" /></root>`;
let parser = new DOMParser();
let xml = parser.parseFromString(str, "application/xml");
for (let node of xml.documentElement.childNodes) {
  // do stuff with nodes that are not `#comment` nodes
  if (node.nodeType !== 8) {
    console.log(node)
  }
}
</script>
```